# Cannot drag full desktop and app windows lose position when being the desktop is dragged to another monitor in macOS Mojave Beta (10.14.1)

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have several application windows open in one of the desktops on my MacBook Pro (late 2016) running macOS Mojave Beta (10.14.1), and have a Dell monitor connected.

Whenever I want to move a fullscreen application window to the other monitor from my Mac, all I have to do is just pull up the Mission Control and drag it to the other monitor.

But when I try dragging the full desktop—that has all of the app windows arranged in a certain way—it does not get to the other monitor.

That leaves me having to arrange the app windows separately on the other monitor. Is there any way I can make this simple?